# Get first object from array of object vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**How can i get array of object first object id?**

here's my arrray's content

0: {id: 1, user_id: 1, user2_id: 2, created_at: "2021-03-22T16:37:10.000000Z",…}

1: {id: 7, user_id: 1, user2_id: 3, created_at: "2021-03-24T16:24:47.000000Z",…}

2: {id: 8, user_id: 1, user2_id: 1, created_at: "2021-03-24T18:19:21.000000Z",…

```
<script>

export default 
{    
    data(){
    return{
        convs_id: [],
        convs: [],
        }
 
    },
    
    created(){
        
        this.fetchConversation();
        this.convs_id = this.convs[0].id;
        console.log(this.convs_id);
    },
    methods:
    {
        fetchConversation()
        {
            axios.get('getConvs').then(response=>{
                this.convs = response.data;
                
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.convs` gets populated when the call to get the data has resolved. So in order to use it you have to wait for that promise to resolve.

To be able to wait on a promise, you have to `return` it. So  `fetchConversation()` needs to return `axios.get()` (which is the promise you'll be waiting on):

```js
methods:{
  fetchConversation() {
    return axios.get('getConvs').then(response => {
      this.convs = response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

---

Now, that `fetchConversation()` returns the promise, you have two ways of waiting on it: either make `created` `async` and use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```js
async created() {
  await this.fetchConversation();
  console.log(this.convs[0]);
}
```

or call [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method on the promise:

```js
created() {
  this.fetchConversation().then(() => {
    console.log(this.convs[0]);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In request success callback extract the first item :

```
export default 
{    
    data(){
      return {
           convs_id: null,
           convs: [],
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.fetchConversation();
       
    },
    methods:
    {
        fetchConversation()
        {
            axios.get('getConvs').then(response=>{
                this.convs = response.data;
                let [firstConvs]=this.convs;// es6 syntax of destructing the array
                 this.convs_id = firstConvs.id;
   
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```